# convert df$vec to numeric

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am trying to write a function for my many datasets and using `a$Rural` is not practical in my case and I am trying to get a numeric vector base on `a`

```
df <- data.frame(
  "Values" = c("Gender","Gender","Marital Status","Marital Status","Age","Age"),
  "Mean"= c(0.6934877,  0.8536885,  0.8801737,  0.8998975, 54.6858177, 54.1486680),
  "By"= c("Urban", "Rural", "Urban","Rural","Urban", "Rural")) 

a <- df %>% 
     spread(By, Mean)%>%
     dplyr::group_by(Values)
```

I tired this but fail

```
c <- as.integer(as.character(a[2]));c
```

Expected Results is `[1] 54.1486680  0.8536885  0.8998975` but without using the  `(c <- a$Rural; c )` name of the column in other words how can i assign `a[2]` as numeric
many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `a[2]` is still a `data.frame` with a single column.  It is already a numeric column.  So, there is no need for conversion

```
str(a[2])
#tibble [3 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
# $ Rural: num [1:3] 54.149 0.854 0.9
```

As it is a `tibble`, the `[,2]` won't work as well.  One option is either `[[` or `$`

```
str(a[[2]])
#num [1:3] 54.149 0.854 0.9


as.integer(as.character(a[[2]]))
```

Or another option is `$` with the column names.  As the OP mentioned that it is not a viable option (with indexing the `$` is not possible)

```
a$Rural
```

---

Or in `tidyverse`, we can use `pluck` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
a %>% 
    pluck(2)
 #[1] 54.1486680  0.8536885  0.8998975
```

Or if we need to use only numeric index

```
a %>%
   pull(2)
#[1] 54.1486680  0.8536885  0.8998975
```